# How do I run a .bat file for commands to execute in a second .bat file running a .jar?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

Hey community I need to know how I can run .bat file to eacute a string of text to a .bat file running a .jar to use the command.

also the batch file to run the command in the other batch file will be run from Windows Task Scheduler.

This is for a Minecraft server by the way. anyhow below is the code used to run the .jar in the batch file. the command syntax is just **"stop"**.

---

**server.bat** code

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui.
```

---

So in long terms I need to make a batch file called **stop.bat** to be run from Windows **Task Scheduler**. In the **stop.bat** file I need the file to exacute the command in the **server.bat** file so that the server will stop, after that I can just run the **server.bat** to start the server again.

any thoughts on how this can be done?
basic lay out how this should all work is below.

server-run.bat >>> "Runs" >>> minecraft-server.jar

Task Scheduler >>> "Runs" >>> stop.bat

stop.bat >>> "Executes command in" >>> server-run.bat

Comment: Use [Schtasks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

assuming your server-run.bat file looks something like this:

```
@echo off
:startserver
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui.
:running

pause
REM or whatever you do normally to stop the server
:stopserver
java stop
REM or whatever the command to stop the server is
exit
```

for the file to be able to jump to some mark defined by acalling batch file, you should change it to:

```
@echo off
if "%*" NEQ "" goto %*
:startserver
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui.
:running

pause
REM or whatever you do normally to stop the server
:stopserver
java stop
REM or whatever the command to stop the server is
exit
```

and stop.bat should look aproximately like this:

```
@echo off
start server-run.bat stopserver
```

remem^ber this is just another way of running the server-stop-command directly from stop.bat. if that wouldn't work (beacause it needs an environnement variable or something) this approach will also fail!

(this is beacause you can't directly interfere with a running batch file or its variables, you can only run a copy of it at the same time)

if you wnat to interfere with a running batch file, the easiest way would be to check periodically if a file exists:

```
@echo off
:startserver
if exists stopfile.txt del stopfile.txt
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui.
:running

if exists stopfile.txt goto stopserver
timeout /T 2
goto running 


:stopserver
del stopfile.txt
java stop
REM or whatever the commabd to stop the server is
goto :EOF
exit
```

and stop.bat just does this:

```
@echo off
echo.something >stopfile.txt
exit
```

this will cause the server-running.bat to

-run the server

-check every 2 seconds if stopfile.txt apperared

-if it did, stop the server

(remember to change the dummy lines with the java code,
i have no idea if they are right)

hope this helped in the end